# can we create multiple webdriver instances working simultaneously in a single web page

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have a Web Page which has three Pie-charts in it. Every pie-chart has a different number of sub-parts in it. I want three dedicated driver instances for each pie-chart where every dedicated driver gets the sub-parts in its respective pie-chart and hover the mouse over it.

I have created three Threads for each pie-charts desired logic and they are happening right. But mouse over not happening paralleled on each pie-chart, rather it is happening in sequence.

Note: I have passed the same driver instance as of now in all three class constructors.

Comment: You'd get three browsers opening in regards to those three different drivers, right?

Comment: @marwaha.ks  .. I used Thread Local to prevent that where I set the driver in a synchronized method and getting the same driver when required.

Comment: @marwaha.ks  I want three drivers to be working in a single session/page.